# .Net HotChocolate GraphQL Mutations pick from a list of stings like enum

Tags: .net, graphql, hotchocolate

I have a bunch of data, in a .NET GRaphQL API that are basically list of strings like

```
Public List<string> avarageMessageSize = new List<string>{
"Up to 5 KB",
"Between 5 KB and 4 MB",
Between 4 MB and 20 MB",
"20 MB and bigger"
};
```

When a new Entity is made with a GraphQL Mutation, for other values that are stored in Enums I have input types that let me choose and pick in a mutation to add the correct value, is this also possible for list items, to pick and choose the correct value(string) in a Mutation?

Comment: You can easily make the string an enum. Essentially a GraphQL enum can be represented by any object in .NET

Comment: Thanks, so you don't have the normal enum restrictions? I can make a GraphQl enum of strings?

Comment: Kind of, the enum does not have to be an enum in C#. But they have to follow the GraphQL enum rules. So `Up to 5 KB` would probably be represented by `Up_to_5KB`. But in your .NET API you would just use the `Up to 5 KB` string. And the GraphQL engine would translate it to the enum in GraphQL. You also cannot have arbitrary values anymore, they must be represented by the enum values allowed.

Comment: A yes I see. Thank you! I was stuck on the concept that an enum is basically a collection of named numerical values.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make the string an enum. Essentially a GraphQL enum can be represented by any object in dotnet.

The strings have to follow the GraphQL enum rules. So `Up to 5 KB` would probably be represented by `Up_to_5KB`. But in your dotnet API you would just use the `Up to 5 KB` string.

The GraphQL engine would translate it to the enum in GraphQL. You also cannot have arbitrary values anymore, they must be represented by the enum values allowed in this case.